# Sharing radios with other people

Tags: legal, ht

I am thinking about getting my technician license. Recently, I saw a video from ARRL which said "Ham's also provide communication for events." with a picture of a marathon. My question is what the definition of that is. Does it mean that as a HAM, I can program radios to stay within legal limits and then give them to event staff for the day? Or does it mean that HAM's communicate with each other on behalf of other people? I can't seem to find the answer elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Henrik, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hams communicate with each other on behalf of other people.

An amateur radio operator license is required for someone to act as control operator for an amateur radio station.  A non-licensed person can act communicate over your radio, but a licensed person must be the control operator.  So you can not just give your radio to event staff for the day.

Amateur radio is different from various other services such as FRS, GMRS, land mobile,... which do not require an operator license to use.

Comment: Thanks! Very clear.